# Programmatically highlight UITableView cell

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an iPad app which uses a UISplitViewController (with a UITableView on the left and a detail view on the right). My table view highlights the selected cell in blue when you tap on it.

When I call the following method, the cell is selected but not highlighted in blue:

```
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
```

I have spent literally days fiddling about with various delegate methods and hacks trying to get the cell to highlight programatically just as if it had been tapped. I can't do it.

I've managed to almost get there with this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (shouldHighlightCell)
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPathForCellToHighlight = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

        if ([indexPath isEqual:indexPathForCellToHighlight])
        {
            cell.selected = YES;
            shouldHighlightCell = NO;
        }
    }
}
```

It works as long as I also have this (otherwise it remains selected even when another cell is tapped):

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

    if ([[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:ip] isSelected])
    {
        [[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:ip] setSelected:NO];
    }

    NSIndexPath *iToTheP = indexPath;
    return iToTheP;
}
```

I know this is a weird and convoluted workaround. I wouldn't mind, but it doesn't even work fully. The selected cell loses its highlight if it is scrolled off screen, whereas a cell that has been tapped remains highlighted when scrolled off screen.

I'm absolutely baffled by this. I'm sure this workaround shouldn't even be necessary, that there is a much simpler solution.

Comment: Have you tried using the `setHighlighted:animated:` method of `UITableViewCell`?  (Also, in the code that you include here, you don't show how you are actually making it highlight.  Ie. what happens when you set `shouldHighlightCell`?)

Comment: You did write, that the cell is selected but not highlighted after this call. How do you check that?

Comment: I know the cell is selected because its detail view is displayed on the right of my split view.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried setHighlighted:animated:

Comment: shouldHighlightCell is set to YES when I create the new cell and add it to the top of the table view. That's why I want it highlighted, because the new cell is automatically selected and it's detail view displayed on the right.

Comment: The hack works better when I move shouldHighlightCell = NO; to tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:. This keeps the cell highlighted even when scrolled off the screen, but removes the highlight whenever another cell is tapped. The hack is doing an ok job now. But I lose my selected cell whenever I reload the contents of the table view from the data store. Maybe I need to rewrite the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this to be completely unfixable using all known possibilities. In the end I fixed it by ditching a lot of my code and switching to NSFetchedResultsController instead. NSFetchedResultsController was introduced shortly after I originally wrote this app, and it greatly simplifies the process of using Core Data with UITableViews.
https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/index.html

Answer (score 12):

Please be sure the cell's `selectionStyle` is `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue` and the tableView's `allowsSelection` is set to `YES`.

The method `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` works fine for me. It does highlight the selected cell.

Comment: Thanks. I've checked both these values and they are as they should be.

Answer (score 3):

I went through and tried all these and other solutions and no joy.  In my case the problem (which drove me nuts for 2 hrs) was the following - shortly after I was calling `selectRowAtIndexPath`, I was calling `reloadData` on the `tableview`.  That reload was wiping all the highlighting!  Beware of this pitfall!  With the unnecessary reloading of data call gone, the highlighting happenned as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I also tried many approaches to get the initial selection to display on my single-selection UITableView. What finally worked for me was to defer the selection of the initial row until the table was set up by calling it in my UITableViewController's viewDidAppear:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPathToSelectInitially, animated: false, scrollPosition: .None)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this and it works for me (aka calling the delegate method didSelectRowAtIndexPath)

```
NSIndexPath *defaultIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self tableView:[self tableView] didSelectRowAtIndexPath:defaultIndexPath];
```

PS. I'm using UITableViewController.

Answer (score 0):

It gets the backgroundview with cell border looking like seperator.Do not change the default tableview settings in Interface builder.Make sure UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone is NOT set to selectionstyle.  I am pasting the working code. :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *kCellIdentifier = @"PlayListCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
    }
    MPMediaPlaylist *playList = [playlistCollection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = playList.name;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
     // cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Songs",[playList.items count]];
    MPMediaItemCollection *playListMediaCollection = [playlistCollection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ];

    cell.imageView.image =[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[self getImageForCollection:playListMediaCollection.items]];

    // the main code which make it highlight

    UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:170.0f/255.0 green:170.0f/255.0 blue:170.0f/255.0 alpha:1.0f];
    [bgColorView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
    [bgColorView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
    return cell;
}
```